# How to block a script from accessing its parent directory in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, security, cpanel

One of my clients has a website (let's call it website.com). They would like to install some script an intern developed in a directory (let's say website.com/somescript).

I don't trust that script very much and I'd like to make sure any file in /somescript does not have access to the parent directory.

How can I do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) parameter which can be set in .htaccess in somescript/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

If the script/directory belong to the same user(&group) then you can't stop it from manipulating website.com